# Resizing and Cropping Images with 2 Canvases

Tags: html, canvas, resize, crop, image-resizing

I'm using this [component](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/10/30/resizing-cropping-images-canvas/) to resize images, but I have some issues:

- How to set image size 100% width and height of parent?

I've tried to do like this right after init: `resizeImage(jQuery($container).parent().width(), jQuery($container).parent().height());`
and it works for size, but image is transparent until you resize it.

- I need 2 elements like this on the same page, but second one rewrite context of the first one and any kind of moving image on the first element apply changes only at the second one.

Any ideas how to fix this component?

Comment: Realized, that component is a closure, bit making it nested function doesn't resolve the problem with 2 canvases.

Comment: For those, who looking for solution:http://pastebin.com/hsHf6t62 http://pastebin.com/ndkgEedU